# custom uitableviewcell reset subview frame doesn't work as I wanted

Tags: ios, uitableview

I custom a uitableviewcell with nib, and want to custom the highlighted style. When the cell highlighted, I want to reduce the size of the subview of the cell and keep the position of the imageview in the cell not changing. So, it looks like the frame of a imageview zoomed out, but the image itself stay there not changing its position.

However, this code snippet doesn't work as I wanted.Could anybody help me to figure out where I am wrong. Any help will be appreciated!

tips: the imageview is a subview of self.frameView and frameView is a subview of frameBgView.

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (highlighted)
    {
        self.frameView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGBA(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        CGRect rect = self.frameBgView.frame;
        rect.origin.x += 10;
        rect.size.width -= 20;
        self.frameBgView.frame = rect;

        rect = self.frameView.frame;
        rect.origin.x -= 10;
        self.frameView.frame = rect;

    }
    else
    {
        ....

    }
}
```

EDIT: some screenshots to explain the question:
[image: cell not highlighted]

[image: cell highlighted]

Comment: try this  `self.frameView.bounds = rect;` replace by this line for `self.frameView.frame = rect;`

Comment: @Shan thanks for your suggestion, I have tried that, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: i don't really get your question please if possible add screen shoot if possible, or tell exactly what is your requirement

Comment: @Shan Hi, I have added two screenshots to help to describe my question.The first screenshot is when the cell not highlighted, and the second one is when the cell is highlighted. You see, when highlighted, the image is not in the center

Comment: you are changing the frame of entire cell .. it looks like it has reduced its frame ..  !!

Comment: @Shan oh, I don't change the frame of entire cell. The entire cell's width equal to the screen width, 320.

Comment: ohh k u are changing the frameBgView rite

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59245/discussion-between-shan-and-somnuslee).

Comment: are u using auto layout ..... ?

Comment: i added some sample code check it,

Comment: i hav edited the answer check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oky i tried your solution but i got like this i am posting the code as well as the output how it looks, if there is any problem just comment , i am deleted the `frameBgView` it is not required

code

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
  {
    if (highlighted)
    {
      self.frameView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
      CGRect rect = self.contentView.bounds;
      rect.origin.x += 15;
      rect.size.width -= 30;


    //rect = self.frameView.frame;
    // rect.origin.x -= 10;
      self.frameView.frame = rect;

   }
   else
  {
    self.frameView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    CGRect rect = self.contentView.bounds;
    rect.origin.x += 10;
    rect.size.width -= 20;
    self.frameView.frame = rect;

  }

}
```

and i am not using auto layout .. the result what i got is, before

[image: before selection]

and after highlighted,

[image]

**EDIT:**

this is the cell structure

[image]

as u can see in the picture, in `content view` i hav added `frameView` which is blue in colour, and within `frameView` i hav added `imageView` and also don't forget t set content mode `scale to fill` and also auto resizing masks for both `frameView` and `imageView` for example

autoresizing masks for `content view`

[image]

autoresizing masks for `frameView`

[image]

autoresizing masks for `imageView`

[image]

**END EDIT**

Comment: Hi, Shan, is your cell width 320? It doesn't work for me either. I just thought it was because I use auto-layout, however, after I disabled the auto-layout, it looks like nothing has changed

Comment: wahoo, you hit the point, I know how to fix it now, thanks a lot!